# Rate of change: area and perimeter

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

The side of rectangle $x = 20m$ increases at the rate of $5m/s$, the other side $y=30m$ decreases at $4m/sec$. What is the rate of change o the perimeter and area of the retangle?

If we put this rectangle in the cartesian plan (starting on the origin) , we can calculate it's perimeter and area by $P = 2x + 2y$ and $A=x.y$(maybe I should use $\triangle x$ and $\triangle y$ instead of x and y ). Since my perimeter is lnearly increasing in x and y, we can find $\frac{dP}{dt} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{ \partial t} + \frac{ \partial P }{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} $ = $2 m/sec$

I couldn't do the same with my area (i don't even know if with I did with the perimeter is correct).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\displaystyle\frac{dx}{dt}=5$ and $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dt}=-4$

Now the rate of change of area $$=\frac{d(xy)}{dt}=x\frac{dy}{dt}+y\frac{dx}{dt}$$

Now the rate of change of perimeter $$=\frac{d\{2(x+y)\}}{dt}=\cdots$$

Comment: Yes, I just stopped there (derivating the area). I don't get what you did in your last step

Comment: I mean, with the perimeter is ok, but what should I put in x and y in the area part? The answer is 70$m^2/sec$

Comment: @user2768645,please have a look into the edited version

Comment: @user2768645, Have you noticed $x=20,y=30$

Comment: I did, I know how to find the answer but I don't understand why we have to use this values

Comment: @user2768645, $$20\cdot(-4)+30\cdot5,$$ right??

Comment: Friend, I know how to get the right answer, I just dont understand why we have to substitute this values. I'm not understanding the interpretation (i'm ok with the derivative part, it is just to put the given values do not make sense to me )

Comment: @user2768645, as the rate of change of value at a certain time is dependent on the value at that point

Comment: In the case of the area, we see that it is true. In the case of the perimeter, no

Comment: But yes, indeed I see this clearly now, thanks.

Comment: @user2768645, as perimeter is linear function of the sides unlike the area